# mongodb specifying MongoOptions when connecting to ReplicaSet

Tags: java, mongodb

I recently created a MongoDB replica set but it is useless to me currently because I couldn't find ways to specify options in it.

My old code looks like this :

```
MongoOptions options = new MongoOptions();
options.autoConnectRetry = true;
options.connectionsPerHost = 10000;

mongo = new Mongo("1.1.1.1:27017", options);
```

I read the replica set documentation, but according to that only way to create a connector for replica set in Java is using MongoURI and is as follows

```
mongo = new Mongo(new MongoURI("mongodb://1.1.1.1,1.1.1.251,1.1.1.37"));
```

This partially works because now I don't see any way to mention MongoOptions.

I couldn't find a workaround in the  MongoURI or in Mongo to specify MongoOptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Mongo`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/Mongo.html) class and [`MongoOptions`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoOptions.html) is sort of deprecated now..

Use [`MongoClient`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html) and [`MongoClientOptions`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.html) instead.

From the javadocs :

> You can connect to a replica set using the Java driver by passing a
>   ServerAddress list to the MongoClient constructor. For example:
>
> ```
>  MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(
>    new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017),
>    new ServerAddress("localhost", 27018),
>    new ServerAddress("localhost", 27019)));
> ```

Comment: An example with an array of seed members would be more complete.

Answer (score 2):

See a simple example below, with the use of MongoClientOptions:

```
MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder()
    .connectionsPerHost(20)
    .autoConnectRetry(true)
    .build();

mongo = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(
       new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017),
       new ServerAddress("localhost", 27018)), 
   options);
```